# PHP: How to display posts of specific category using a custom query in WordPress?

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm not using WP language but simple PHP
my code now is

```
SELECT * FROM wp_posts   w
        WHERE  w.post_status = 'publish'
        AND w.post_type = 'post'
        ORDER BY RAND()
        LIMIT 3
```

so i can display 3 random blog article on my custom homepage (not WP)
it works.

but now i'd like to choose a specific category

how can i do it?

Answer (score 0):

```
query_posts('cat=123');
```

This does the trick for a specific category. If the category has a name, equal the value to the name. Although, category ID is recommended (if later changes happen).

Answer (score 0):

You really shouldn't be using a SQL query but rather [WP_Query](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) object or [query_posts](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts) function.

Your query should look like this:

```
$posts = new WP_Query(array(
    'orderby' => rand,
    'posts_per_page' => 3,
    'post_status' => 'publish', 
    'cat' => 123
));
```

If you are using this on your home page then the "query_posts" function would fit better:

```
query_posts(array(
    'orderby' => rand,
    'posts_per_page' => 3,
    'post_status' => 'publish', 
    'cat' => 123
));
```

Category ID is "123" in this case but you can use any of the [category params](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Category_Parameters) here instead.

Answer (score 0):

```
global $wpdb;

$posts = $wpdb->get_results('SELECT ID, post_title AS title, post_excerpt AS excerpt FROM '.$wpdb->posts.' WHERE post_type = "post" AND post_status = "publish" ORDER BY post_date DESC LIMIT 5');
```

Comment: This shows only the last 5 posts but not a specific category